# How to unit test a "disk full" scenario with Ruby RSpec?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rubygems

I need to unit test scenarios like the following:

The disk has 1MB free space. I try to copy 2MB of file(s) to the disk.

What's the best way to do this with Ruby RSpec?

For further information, I need to unit test [the following file cache method](https://github.com/getvictor/buildcache/blob/9be5ffb3c3995482323e7f53567132599b2591da/lib/buildcache.rb#L55-L124), since it appears to have some issue:

```
def set first_key, second_key='', files=[]
  # If cache exists already, overwrite it.
  content_dir = get first_key, second_key
  second_key_file = nil

  begin
    if (content_dir.nil?)

      # Check the size of cache, and evict entries if too large
      check_cache_size if (rand(100) < check_size_percent)

      # Make sure cache dir doesn't exist already
      first_cache_dir = File.join(dir, first_key)
      if (File.exist?first_cache_dir)
        raise "BuildCache directory #{first_cache_dir} should be a directory" unless File.directory?(first_cache_dir)
      else
        FileUtils.mkpath(first_cache_dir)
      end
      num_second_dirs = Dir[first_cache_dir + '/*'].length
      cache_dir = File.join(first_cache_dir, num_second_dirs.to_s)
      # If cache directory already exists, then a directory must have been evicted here, so we pick another name
      while File.directory?cache_dir
        cache_dir = File.join(first_cache_dir, rand(num_second_dirs).to_s)
      end
      content_dir = File.join(cache_dir, '/content')
      FileUtils.mkpath(content_dir)

      # Create 'last_used' file
      last_used_filename = File.join(cache_dir, 'last_used')
      FileUtils.touch last_used_filename
      FileUtils.chmod(permissions, last_used_filename)

      # Copy second key
      second_key_file = File.open(cache_dir + '/second_key', 'w+')
      second_key_file.flock(File::LOCK_EX)
      second_key_file.write(second_key)

    else
      log "overwriting cache #{content_dir}"

      FileUtils.touch content_dir + '/../last_used'
      second_key_file = File.open(content_dir + '/../second_key', 'r')
      second_key_file.flock(File::LOCK_EX)
      # Clear any existing files out of cache directory
      FileUtils.rm_rf(content_dir + '/.')
    end

    # Copy files into content_dir
    files.each do |filename|
      FileUtils.cp(filename, content_dir)
    end
    FileUtils.chmod(permissions, Dir[content_dir + '/*'])

    # Release the lock
    second_key_file.close
    return content_dir
  rescue => e
    # Something went wrong, like a full disk or some other error.
    # Delete any work so we don't leave cache in corrupted state
    unless content_dir.nil?
      # Delete parent of content directory
      FileUtils.rm_rf(File.expand_path('..', content_dir))
    end
    log "ERROR: Could not set cache entry. #{e.to_s}"
    return 'ERROR: !NOT CACHED!'
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to stub out methods that write to disk to raise an error. For example, for the specs that test disk space errors, you could try:

```
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(File).to receive(:open) { raise Errno::ENOSPC }
  # or maybe # allow(File).to receive(:write) { raise Errno::ENOSPC }
  # or       # allow(FileUtils).to receive(:cp) { raise Errno::ENOSPC }
  # or some combination of these 3...
end

it 'handles an out of disk space error' do
  expect{ my_disk_cache.set('key1', 'key2', [...]) }.to # your logic for how BuildCache::DiskCache should handle the error here.
end
```

There are two problems with this however:

1) `Errno::ENOSPC` may not be the error you actually see getting raised. That error fits the description in your question, but depending on the peculiarities of your lib and the systems it runs on, you might not really be getting an `Errno::ENOSPC` error. Maybe you run out of RAM first and are getting `Errno::ENOMEM`, or maybe you have too many file descriptors open and are getting `Errno::EMFILE`. Of course if you want to be rigorous you could handle all of these, but this is time consuming and you'll get diminishing returns for handling the more obscure errors.

[See this](http://blog.honeybadger.io/understanding-rubys-strange-errno-exceptions/) for more information on Errno errors.

2) This solution involves stubbing a specific method on a specific class. (`File.open`) This isn't ideal because it couples the setup for your test to the implementation in your code. That is to say, if you refactor `BuildCache::DiskCache#set` to not use `File.open`, then this test might start failing even though the method might be correct.

That said, `File.open` is fairly low level. I know that some `FileUtils` methods use `File.open`, (Notably, `FileUtils.cp`) so I would suggest just using that first `allow_any_instance_of` line. I'd expect that to handle most of your use cases.

Alternatively, there is a tool called [`fakefs`](https://github.com/fakefs/fakefs) that may be able to help you with this. I am not familiar with it, but it may well have functionality that helps with testing such errors. You may want to look into it.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, there's no ready-made tool for stubbing disk IO. There's a tool called [`webmock`](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) for dealing with this same basic problem, but with web IO instead... I searched a bit, but didn't find anything myself.

Comment: Scratch that, there's a tool called [fakefs](https://github.com/fakefs/fakefs) that _may_ be able to help you. I'd check it out. Edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of any of the method calls you know are happening inside of the method you need to test, and stub them so they raise an error. E.g. `FileUtils.touch` is called a number of times, so we could do:

```
it 'handles file write error gracefully' do
  allow(FileUtils).to receive(:touch).and_raise('oh no')
  # your expectations
  # your test trigger
end
```